# how call javascript exactly at time

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('send_order_btnSendOrder').click();
}
```

and I want to run this code exactly in 8:29:59:999 time of day

my mean is I want exactly at the time of 8:29:59:999, click on the selected button
what must to do?

Comment: First no way you will get it that exact, second/millisecond, JavaScript is the wrong thing for this.

Comment: Assuming that the page is always running, using `setTimeout` might be useful (compute the time remaining from now until then and wait for it). Getting the "exact" time will be hard, but it should be possible to get "close to" the time (within 10-30ms). Of course, if the browser is closed then - no timer. If there is a connection issue with the server or the the connection to the server is slow then the time on the server will be incorrect. Likewise, if the local machine's clock is not 100% accurate with server time.. (so a mere 10-30ms is quite reasonable from the initiating click).

Comment: @user2864740 there's no `setTimer` function in JS. @epascarello is right, you'd be hard pressed to get this exact. Setting up a cron job might be an option, but need more information on your setup.

Comment: @Phix Yeah, was a fat-finger typo. Cron alone would do no better (and actually be 'worse') at this task in terms of precision.

Comment: it's not even exact second @epascarello - it's exact millisecond!

Comment: if you're trying to create a auction sniping bot, this is not the way to do it